# Installing libssl-dev failing

Tags: linux, debian

I'm working on a Debian box and trying to install libssl-dev, but am getting the following error when I try. Anybody have a solution?

```
# sudo apt-get install libssl-dev

Reading package lists... Done  
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done  

Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.  

The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:  
  libssl-dev: Depends: libssl0.9.8 (= 0.9.8g-15+lenny13) but 0.9.8o-4~bpo50+1 is to be installed  
E: Broken packages
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The unmet dependencies statement is the key here.  It appears there's a mismatch in the version of libssl the -dev package needs and the version available on whatever repository you're using.  The distro specification for the two is different (lenny vs bpo), are you sure your repositories are set up correctly?  You could try explicitly specifying a version number (the same one) for both:

```
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev=0.9.8g-15+lenny13 libssl0.9.8=0.9.8g-15+lenny13
```

If one isn't in the repo, look at the repos and pick a version that is.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you've got some generational differences in packages - your `libssl-dev` seems to be trying to install from the main package repository for lenny, while `libssl0.9.8` looks like it's already installed from backports.

You'll need to resolve this by getting the versions to where they don't conflict - what do you get from `apt-cache policy libssl-dev` and `apt-cache policy libssl0.9.8`, and do you know why this backports version was installed in the first place?